# Answering "Can I sue?" questions

Tags: discussion, common-questions

As the complement to [Answering "Can I be sued?" questions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224/10): I really like [this as a general answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/1775/10).  Just thought it was worth noting as part of the canon of [common-questions](/questions/tagged/common-questions).